# How can I pass some values from one view to another view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an application done on Code-igniter.

I wanted to pass title and URL to another page when I click on a link to the next page.

**For e.g.** 
Page one - **properties/home/details/titleofthecontent** - in this page i have a link **report it** .

When i click on **report it** i will get next page */report_abuse* .Here I need to get the page title and the URL from the previous page.

I have the variable to pass but how could I pass it? This is same as passing values from one view to another view.

Comment: Make a unique session variable and store all your variable there and retrieve that variable in next page. You can unset them after use

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller, have

```
$data['nestedView']['otherData'] = 'testing';
```

before your view includes.

When you call

```
$this->load->view('view_destinations',$data);
```

the view_destinations file is going to have

```
$nestedView['otherData'];
```

Which you can at that point, pass into the nested view file.

Answer (score 0):

From what you explain, I understand that you want to pass some data from a controller to another (since your URL's are different).

To do this, you can:

1. Pass the data through query strings (GET) as explained above or
2. Set a flash data variable in the first controller, and use it in the second. I would advise to use this solution, as that's why flash data exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $this->uri->segment() of Codeigniter like below.

```
$this->uri->segment(1); // controller
$this->uri->segment(2); // action
$this->uri->segment(3); // 1stsegment
$this->uri->segment(4); // 2ndsegment
```

You can pass the variables values via url and get on the controller. and so on.